# Craving for Non-Kosher Food

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, food, pregnancy-birth

If a pregnant lady craves for something not kosher is she permitted to eat it? Source? Does it depend how much she wants it, etc.?

Comment: here http://baalteshuva1.blogspot.com/2014/03/rabbi-shlomo-schwartz-on-parshas-shmini.html

Answer (score 2):

See Masechet Yoma 82a

> ת"ר עוברה שהריחה בשר קודש או בשר חזיר תוחבין לה כוש ברוטב ומניחין לה על פיה עד שתתיישב דעתה אם נתיישב מוטב ואם לאו מאכילין אותה שומן
>
> Our Rabbis taught: If a woman with child smelt the flesh of holy flesh, or of pork,
>
> 1. we put for her a reed into the juice and place it upon her mouth. If thereupon she feels that her craving has been satisfied, it is well.
> 2. If not, one feeds her with the juice itself. If thereupon her craving is satisfied
> 3. if it is not one feeds her with the fat meat itself,

Kretot 13a:

> A pregnant woman is permitted to eat a quantity smaller than the standard size, because of her serious position.
>
> It is stated, 'A pregnant woman is permitted to eat a quantity smaller than the standard size, because of her serious position'.  If by reason of her serious position, she should be permitted to eat even more! - Said R`Papa: Read thus, A pregnant woman is permitted to eat even more, yet in quantities smaller than the standard size, because of her serious position.

A summary, Rambam Maachalot Asurot 14, 14:

> עוברה שהריחה מאכל אסור, כגון בשר קודש או בשר חזיר--מאכילין אותה מן המרק.  אם נתיישבה דעתה, מוטב;‏
>
> **First trial**, with juice of the prohibited meat;
>
> ואם לאו, מאכילין אותה פחות פחות מכשיעור.‏
>
> **Second trial**, with a volumetric quantity of meat smaller than an olive;
>
> ואם לא נתיישבה דעתה, מאכילין אותה עד שתתיישב דעתה.‏
>
> **We try with ascendant quantities** until she feels good. {in the crescendo, we try to addition infra regular quantities with an intereating time great to achilat pras (approximately 9 minutes following stringent authorities, less for others) and if she needs to eat faster she can eat faster. For drins the quantity is reviit, approximately 9 ml.}.

See SA OC 617:   SA 618, 7 regarding eating at Yom Kippur:

> כשמאכילין את העוברות או את החולה מאכילין אותם מעט מעט כדי שלא יצטרף לשיעור הלכך מאכילין אותו כשני שלישי ביצה בינונית וישהו כדי אכילת ארבעה ביצים והשתיה יבדקו בחולה עצמו כמה היא כדי שיסלקנו לצד אחד ויראה כמלא לוגמיו:‏

Answer (score 1):

The Mishnah in *Maseches Yoma* ([8:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yoma.8.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) writes:

> עוברה שהריחה מאכילין אותה עד שתשיב נפשה
>
> A pregnant woman who smells [food], we feed it to her until she recovers.

Rambam (*Pirush HaMishnayos* ibid s.v. עוברה) explains:

> עוברה שהריחה בשר קדש או בשר חזיר ונתעורר טבעה ותאותה לאכול מאכילין אותה ממנו עד שיתישב נפשה
>
> A pregnant woman who smells holy [sacrificial] meat, or pig meat, and it awakened in her a desire to eat [it], we feed it to her until she recovers.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP is looking for a practical, modern, halachik ruling. But that's just my guess.

Comment: @user6591 AFAIK it is the halacha.

Comment: @SAH I have honestly never heard of a pregnant woman desiring nonkosher and eating it, so afaik, idk. Especially since this may be categorized as a refua in the Talmud which we usually do not rule in accordance with.